# Solve simple nonlinear equations in the form [A]x=b

Tags: matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a simple set of nonlinear equations

1) 3x = 30

2) x+2y = 20

3) x + y*z = 15

Clearly the solution to this is (10,5,1) but I want to find a robust way to solve this type of problem [A]x=b (where [A] is a simple function of x) which doesn't involve numerically solving using Newtons method.

```
{{3,0,0},{1,2,0},{1,z,0}} {{x},{y},{z}} = {{30}, {20}, {15}}
```

[image: Picture in matrix form]

Comment: I know what a nonlinear system is, but not what a nonlinear matrix is. I don't think your question makes sense. If $A$ is a matrix, then $Ax=b$ is a linear equation. If $Ax=b$ somehow represents a nonlinear system, then $A$ is not a matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The fact that $A$ contains an unknown rather than just coefficients means it's not a matrix any more?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I have edited my post. I was under the impression that a linear system is where [A]x=b (where [A] just contains constants), and a nonlinear system is where [A]x=b (where [A] contains x). Sorry for the confusion. Is there a way to still solve the system of equations I've got without manually deconstructing each one? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manually deconstructing". I suppose that you can just use the usual way of solving linear systems – row reduction to echelon form, by using elementary row operations – to see what comes out. In your example, you get down to $x=10$, $y=5$, $0=5-5z$.